# How to return a simple string in WCF Global Error Handling?

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to implement the global error handling in WCF using the `IErrorHandler` interface but in case of an unhandled exception, I want to return a simple string (this is the return type of my service).

How can I achieve this? `IErrorHandler.ProvideFault()` sets the `fault` argument to `Message` type and `Message.ToString()` generates an XML-like response. This is not working for me, because my client wants to get a simple string in a specific format.

Comment: If I understand correctly - your service method already returns a string. You have a specific string that you want to return from the service if an exception occurs?

Comment: @ScottHannen yes, exactly. and i want to do this from the global error handler.

Comment: I can provide a way to do it that's not from the global error handler, but doesn't require you to write the same code in every service method.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler(v=vs.110).aspx),

> IErrorHandler enables you to explicitly control the SOAP fault generated

It's not for changing the actual return value of the service.

If I understand correctly, your service already returns a string. If an error occurs, you want your service to return a particular string.

In its simplest form, this would look like this:

```
public string YourServiceMethod(int someInput)
{
    try
    {
        // Do whatever the method does
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // Log the exception, probably?
        return "This is the specific error message I want to return."
    }
}
```

If you want to avoid writing that same code in every method, one way to accomplish that is using an interceptor, such as with [Castle Windsor's dependency injection container](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/README.md).

That means modifying the whole WCF service to use Windsor (or some similar DI framework) but it's worth it for lots of other reasons. I use it for every WCF service I write. Here's a [tutorial](http://scotthannen.org/blog/2016/04/13/wcf-dependency-injection-in-5-minutes.html) on how to add Windsor to your WCF service in five minutes.

Then you would write a class called an interceptor. It might look something like this:

```
public class ErrorMessageInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        try
        {
            invocation.Proceed();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // log your exception
            invocation.ReturnValue = "Your specific error message.";
        }
    }
}
```

Then, when you register your service with the container you would do this:

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<IInterceptor>().ImplementedBy<ServerLogInterceptor>()
       .Named("ErrorMessageInterceptor"));

container.Register(Component.For<IYourService,YourService>()
   .Interceptors("ErrorMessageInterceptor"));
```

where `IYourService` is your service interface and `YourService` is the actual service class.

This means that every time an instance of `YourService` is activated, an instance of `ErrorMessageInterceptor` is created. All calls to the service's method are "intercepted" by the interceptor's `Intercept` method. It's essentially putting a `try/catch` around the method call without directly adding it into the original method.

If you needed to you could be more specific. For example, your interceptor could check `invocation.Method.ReturnType` to see if the method returns a string, and only add your error message then.

You can do some great stuff with interceptors. A scenario like this where you're trying to something small is a great opportunity to try working with them. If you haven't used DI with WCF before it looks weird, but likewise once you try it you might find that it's a very useful pattern.

Comment: Hi,
tanks for that idea i really wasnt think in that direction but it's make sense
and i already changing my code to use Castle so its looks like good option for my needs.